# Fields in Unpivot and column query reults

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

*(note errors regarding The type of column "mydate" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list is not the issue and I edited the code I supplied to resolve that error.  The question I have is how to get the fields used in the pivot as columns in the query results)*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[iAudit](
    [ProdId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ProdName] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Category] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [AgeGroup] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [IsInternal] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [myDate] [varchar] (10) NULL

) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into [dbo].[iAudit]
values
('1',   'Cars', 'A',    '18',   'yes','2020-01-01'),
('2',   'Bikes',    'B',    '6',    'yes','2020-01-02'),
('3',   'Kites',    'C',    '10',   'no','2020-01-03'),
('4',   'Scooter',  'D',    '6',    'no','2020-01-04'),
('5',   'Glider',   'E',    '16',   'no','2020-01-05')
```

I then unpivot the table

```
select Code, [Value]
from
( select ProdId, ProdName, Category, AgeGroup, IsInternal from dbo.iAudit) p
unpivot
(
Value for Code in (p.ProdId, p.ProdName, p.Category, p.AgeGroup, p.IsInternal)
) as unpvt
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My question is how can I have 'myDate' as part of the pivot and also as a column of the query results?

My desired outcome is something like this:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Notice how 'myDate' is part of the unpivot and a column in the output.  Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgGBK.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c67py.png

Comment: *"My question is how can I have 'myDate' as part of the pivot and also as a column of the query results?"* Yes, you can; what's stopping you?

Comment: You should post the error message - Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The type of column "mydate" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: Please publish your desired outcome as text.

Comment: All unpivot values must have same (or compatible) datatype. when you fix that, the rest will be easy like sunday morning. one idea is to cast the date to varchar of some sort.

Comment: cast(CONVERT(varchar, mydate, 23) as varchar(10)) mydate resolves at least part of your question.

Comment: I've adjusted my initial post.  When I try to add 'myDate' to the select statement I get the error: Invalid column name 'myDate'


select Code as FieldName, [Value], myDate
from
( select ProdId, ProdName, Category, AgeGroup, IsInternal, myDate from iAudit) p
unpivot
(
Value for Code in (p.ProdId, p.ProdName, p.Category, p.AgeGroup, p.IsInternal, myDate)
) as unpvt

Comment: You're unpivoting `MyDate`, so it's not a column any more, it's a row value. if you actually provided expect results in your question (in a consumable format, such as markdown table) it would be much easier to understand what your goal is here.

Comment: ;WITH p as(SELECT ProdId, ProdName, Category, AgeGroup, IsInternal, myDate, myDate2=myDate FROM [dbo].[iAudit]) 
SELECT Code, [Value], myDate=myDate2
FROM p
UNPIVOT([Value] FOR Code IN ( p.ProdId, p.ProdName, p.Category, p.AgeGroup, p.IsInternal, p.myDate))unpvt

Comment: Thank you Der U, that's exactly the result I was attempting to get.